# Hi, I'm trying to get value of my ticks but whenever i return any function always getting value with __zone_symbol__state and __zone_symbol__value

Tags: angular, ionic3

1. which is my function :

   ```
   getTicks(){
      return this.storage.get('myData').then((data) => {
          return this.ticks = data.ticks;
      });
    }
   ```
2. Here i am getting the value of my function return call

   ```
   ionViewDidLoad() {
       this.getTicks();
       console.log('value', this.getTicks());
   }
   ```

I am getting value like this, i don't want to zone symbol , i want only "63628978458585976676676" my value return.

```
{ 
__zone_symbol__state: true 
__zone_symbol__value: "636289784552662421"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTicks()` function is returning a *promise* object returned by `this.storage.get('myData')` which you are logging in the console.

You need to print within a `then`.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.getTicks().then(data=>{
        console.log('value', data);
    });
}
```